# How do I get zsh 5.xx on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, zsh

I have a docker container with ubuntu 18.04 on it.

after `apt-get update` I do:

```
# apt-get install zsh-beta
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package zsh-beta
```

Is there a special repository for this I need to add? Is there an apt package for 5.xx?

I get the same response on a non-virtual Ubuntu.

This appears to be required dependency for the "rvm" ruby manager package.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like [the `zsh` package has 5.4.2 in 18.04 (Bionic)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/zsh). Are you looking for something past that version?